# Prove $2^n = O(n!)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I proved by induction that for all $n \leq 4$,
$2^n+1 \lt (n+1)!$, therefore $2^n \lt n!$, but I just don't know how to prove the big $O$.

I know the definition that there exists $c$ for which $n! \leq c \cdot 2n$, but I just don't understand how to find $c$.

Comment: I think both of your `\leq` meant to be `\geq`

Comment: You won’t find c, because you wrote the inequality the wrong way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

To go from $2^n$ to $2^{n+1}$, you multiply by $2$.

To go from $n!$ to $(n+1)!$, you multiply by $n+1$.

For almost all $n$, $n+1\geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

You got it backwards, and wrote $2n$ instead of $2^n$.  So you want $2^n\le c\cdot n!$.  But if you write it out, you have $2\cdot2\dots2/(n\cdot (n-1)\dots2\cdot1)=2/n\cdot2/(n-1)\cdot\dots2/2\cdot2/1\le2$.  So we are done.

Actually, we also have that, since $n!$ increases faster than $2^n$, $2^n=o(n!)$.  But when one function is little-oh of another function, that implies that it is also big-oh of it.